# How do you get the attachment link after uploading a video media via Facebook Messenger Upload API?

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

We're trying to retrieve an attachment that we uploaded via Facebook Messenger Upload API, but we can't seem to get any info about the attachment link. We only have the attachment id.

Is there a way to get the attachment link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working now. I basically need to create an attachment payload passing only the attachmend_id.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "USER_ID"
  },
  "message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "image",
      "payload": {
        "attachment_id": "1745504518999123"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

This will send the existing attachment to the user.